# Angular Typescript and HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface GeneralInfo{
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
}
```

Later in a component class, I have the following code

```
export class SignalsComponent implements OnInit {
    objGeneral: GeneralInfo;

constructor(private _apiService: APIService)

openPopUp(){
    this._apiService.getJsonData().subscribe(
            (res => {                
                var tempJson = JSON.parse(res);
                this.objGeneral = tempJson.General as GeneralInfo;
                console.log("json --->", this.objGeneral.Description);
            }),
            (err => { })
        );

}
}
```

When I look at the browser console all works and I see the data I expect to see. However, when I try to invoke the objGeneral.Description property in HTML, it fails. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
   {{objGeneral.Description}}
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Probably the HTML is rendering before the data is retrieved from the server. You need to use the objGeneral.Description only inside the callback function or in a place where you are sure the callback has already been called. I'd recommend to leave the HTML empty and change its content after the console.log()

Comment: “it fails”, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Quick answer**

Add a condition to your div :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" *ngIf="objGeneral">
   {{objGeneral.Description}}
</div>
```

Or use optional chaining if you still want to render an empty div :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    {{objGeneral?.Description}}
</div>
```

Note that you can use optional chaining in condition :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" *ngIf="objGeneral?.Description">
```

**2) Complete answer**

`objGeneral` is still not defined when your DOM is rendering, it will be defined when the Observable completes. Means you are asking the DOM to render undefined data.

> When I look at the browser console all works

Weird, because you should have this type of error in your console which prevents you to call the property of an undefined object :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Description')
```

**3) Ressources & useful links you might want to check for more information**
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-beauty-of-optional-chaining-in-typescript-32dd58ce1380

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is incorrect - objGeneral exists only after async API call. Instead you should deliver this property via async pipe

```
export class SignalsComponent implements OnInit {
    objGeneral$: BehavioutSubject<GeneralInfo> | null;

constructor(private _apiService: APIService)

openPopUp(){
    this.objGeneral$ = this._apiService.getJsonData().pipe(
      map(res => JSON.parse(res).General as GeneralInfo)
    );
}
}
```

and use it as

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" *ngIf="objGeneral$ | async as objGeneral">
    {{objGeneral.Description}}
</div>
```